# Is travel history needed for Estonia?

Tags: international-travel, nigerian-citizens, estonia

Do I need travel history for Estonia? I am applying from Nigeria.

Answer (score 7):

Estonia is part of the Schengen area, so you will have to meet the same requirements there as for any other Schengen area country.

You don't *need* a travel history to get a visa anywhere. However, if you can demonstrate that you have travelled and obeyed the rules in the countries you have travelled to that will make your case stronger.

If you can show that you can support yourself during your stay, and that you have strong ties to your home country that give you a good reason to leave, you may be able to get a Schengen visa without a travel history.