# Is travel history required for Iceland and Estonia

Tags: schengen-visas, iceland, nigerian-citizens, estonia

I am a Nigerian, I understand the issue of travel history problems. But i want to know something, Please does Estonia and Iceland require travel history to apply for a tourist Visa? I  work in a Bank here as a software Engineer, with a good salary, but i am not married.

Kindly advise.

Comment: You’ve asked basically the same question before https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151267/is-travel-history-needed-for-estonia

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is travel History needed for Estonia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151267/is-travel-history-needed-for-estonia)

Comment: Please do not ask repeated questions, adding one more Schengen country does not really change the question. If you had asked a single question about Iceland that would have been understandable, but the combination of the two does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

No countries requires you to show a travel history in order to get a tourist visa.

Instead, your previous travels are just one of many things that they will consider when determining if they will issue you a visa or not.  Countless other criteria, including you financial status, your family situations, you job/career, real estate, other ties to your current residence, criminal history, how you act during the interview, etc, etc will all be considered.

In general the intent is to determine if you are likely to remain (illegal) in the country the visa is being issued for, or if you will return to your home country. Being able to show a previous history of returning home after travel will help them make that determination, but it's far from being the only criteria.